# Convert C# Table into PDF file

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I'm trying to put my Table (System.Web.UI.WebControls) into pdf by using StringWriter & HtmlTextWriter, but i'm getting a pdf file with an error.

here is my code :

```
        table.RenderControl(htw);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Reception.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        //render the htmlwriter into the response  
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(headerTable);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

i got "error in loading document pdf" when i open pdf file.

Comment: What is the error? In order for anyone to help you, you must provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example. This includes posting reproducible code as well as the error.

Comment: i got "error in loading document pdf" when i open the file.

Comment: What is sw? It contains a valid pdf byte array or what?

Comment: sw it's StringWriter & htw it's HtmlTextWriter.

Comment: But what does it contain?

Comment: System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);    (htw is just to convert my table to pdf)

Comment: What does it actually contain? What kind of data is in it? Is the data in PDF format?

Comment: wellllllll it's a normal table contains data (several rows and column), the same table work fine for Excel but not for PDF.

Comment: Well then, in order to be able to open it as PDF, you have to convert it to PDF first; not just save it with PDF extension. Right?

Comment: mannnn it's the role of StringWriter & HtmlTextWriter, the data converted to PDF !!!.

Comment: @AnisBenKhiroun *" it's the role of StringWriter & HtmlTextWriter"* - No. Their role is to write *Strings* or *HtmlText*, and PDF is neither of them.

Comment: well it's done with iTextSharp, thanks humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the class iTextSharp is pertinent to make this work..
I changed my code to this:

```
        table.RenderControl(htw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Reception.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```